# how i can un-post my modern page from being set as News inside our site

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, sitepages, modern-pages

I am working on a sharepoint online team site collection, and i added a new Modern site page, and after i publish it i got a message which allow me to post my page as a News inside our site, so i click on it:-

[image]

after that this page start to show inside our News modern web part. Now i am trying to find a way if i can un-post our page from the News modern web part, but i could not find any. For example i navigate to the page and i click on the Promote link, where i got this :-

[image]

and could not find any option that can allow me to un-post my page from the News web part. so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DemoteNewsArticle` method the `PnPClientSidePage` to `un-publish` it as news article.

Use the PnP commands as mentioned below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test"
# url of the page without aspx or title of the page
# if your page url is Test.aspx, pass the Identity parameter as Test
$clientSidePage = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Test"
$clientSidePage.DemoteNewsArticle()
```

If you want to Promote it again, the use:

```
$clientPage.PromoteAsNewsArticle()
```

Reference - [ClientSidePage.DemoteNewsArticle Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/officedevpnp.core.pages.clientsidepage.demotenewsarticle?view=sharepointpnpcoreonline-2.18.1709.0)

**Update**  - No way its possible OOTB. However, the whether its published as news or not is determined by `PromotedState` column value. You can choose via PowerShell to show its value in the edit form of the Site Page. Now, when the value is set to 0, it will be unpublished , when its set to 2 , it will show up in the news.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test"
$context = Get-PnPContext
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "Site Pages"
$context.Load($list.Fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$field = $list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("PromotedState")
$field.SetShowInEditForm($true)
$field.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

This column is by default hidden, so we are just showing it on the edit properties page. So, if by mistake some user has posted it as news, they can simply change the value to 0 in the edit form.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply,, So you mean i can not do this from the UI itself? what if a contributor user post the page as News by mistake? then this user can not un-post the page? looks weird how sharepoint online is managing this??

Comment: Check updated answer. Looks like nobody has faced this scenario :)

Comment: but i always try not to show fields which sharepoint hide by defualt, as i am not sure why sharepoint has chosen to hide this column by default , and i am also not sure if there are any risks of showing this filed in edit form?? i did not find any documentation about this

Comment: Because there isn't :) , as far as i know there is no risk in doing this. Also, check the links [here](https://products.office.com/en-IN/business/office-365-roadmap?filters=&featureid=27251#abc) ,[here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Communications-Sites-AMA/Extend-News-Pages-with-custom-properties-e-g-Managed-Meta-Data/td-p/83184) and [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/31437259-enable-custom-columns-for-modern-pages). Lots of suggestions and a product roadmap suggesting that this will be available in the near future.

Comment: thanks for the code,, but for getting the site pages seems i can use this code using `.aspx` as follow `$clientSidePage = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Meeting-Agenda-2018.aspx"`. OR using this code without `.aspx` as follow `$clientSidePage = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Meeting-Agenda-2018"`.. so will this get me the same result? now my page url is as follow `https://*****.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Meeting-Agenda-2018.aspx`?? in other words does this function `Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity` allow me to get the site page either using `.aspx` or without using `.aspx`??

Comment: both are fine AFAIK

Comment: i think so also

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's easy with a grouped view, where you move them between page status groups.
https://youtu.be/ZhVoYyo9TY4?t=75

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online received a recent update providing an Unpublish option in the Show actions drop-down menu.

[image: Show actions --> More --> Unpublish]

This update should already be available to everyone.  If you still do not see the option, ensure you have the Document Version History set to Create major and minor versions for the Site Pages Library and it should appear.

[image: Document Library Version Control]